# Updating referenced images

Tags: image, latex

I am sketching graphs with Matplotlib and saving as PNG using the `save.fig()` command as follows:

```
plt.savefig("Landing_Configuration.png")
```

I am also making tables using pandas and saving as PNG as follows:

```
k_distance = h_CoG - h_Merlin_nozzle
print(k_distance)

Optimised_Landing = (Iyy_Total_AboutBaseThrusters / 10e6)
Simplified_Landing = (m_Total * (h_CoG**2) / 10e6)

def SmallTable():    
    Landing_Config_list = [round(Optimised_Landing, 2), round(Simplified_Landing, 2), round(h_CoG, 2), round(h_CoG/h_Total * 100, 2), round(k_distance, 2)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(Landing_Config_list, columns = ['Moment of Inertia — Landing'],index=["Optimised_Landing I (kTonnes/m^2)", 
                                                                                                 "Simplified_Landing I (kTonnes/m^2)", 
                                                                                                 "CoG distance from Rocket Base (m)", 
                                                                                                 "CoG distance from Rocket Base (%)",
                                                                                                 "CoG distance from Centre of Thrust (m)"])
    
    dfi.export(df, 'Landing_I.png')
                      
    return (display_side_by_side(df))
```

I am saving these PNG files locally in a Jupyter Notebook Folder. I then upload them to LaTeX and organise them inside a LaTeX folder called "images" from where I include them in my document using `\includegraphics(images/file_name.png)`.

Although I was previously able to have my figures updated, it is not impossible.

I have tried removing them from the images file, renaming them and trying to update them outside of the `/minipage` command.

I am now only able to update images by reuploading them on LATEX.

Is there a way to regain the updating capability?

Comment: 1. Check if the images in the `image` folder are the new ones

Comment: 2. make a [mre] of your document and show your .log file

Comment: 3. how do you compile your document?

Comment: (4. for plots and tables, it would really be much better to safe them as vector graphics like pdf and not png)

Comment: Images are not updated in the latex folder

Comment: ok, so nothing to do with latex. Maybe rewrite your question (including the tags) and focus on how you upload your images to your folder?